# Sanitizing data / SQL injections in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In the [CakePHP Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) it states

```
CakePHP handles SQL escaping on all parameters to Model::find() and Model::save().
```

I was reading up on security and sanitizing data with CakePHP and I came across [this](http://nooclear.com/content/cakephp-20-protect-your-application-sql-injection) blog post.

In the author's first two examples (assuming you're using Cake 2.X), is it true that if you set a variable to some POST data, then use that variable in a find statement you're still vulnerable to SQL injection?

The author states in this example Cake will protect you from SQL injection

```
$articles = $this->Article->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.date' => $this->request->data['Article']['date'],
                )
            )
        );
```

Where as this one would leave you vulnerable to SQL injection unless you use the sanitize utility on the $date variable.

```
$date = $this->request->data['Article']['date']
$articles = $this->Article->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        "Article.date='{$date}'",
                    )
                )
            );
```

Seeing as they're both the same value ($date and $this->request->data['Article']['date']), does Cake actually handle them differently?

Also, I noticed the CakePHP documents state Sanitize is deprecated as of 2.4. I'm currently using 2.3.9. Is it still OK to use it, or should I switch to a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

**EDIT**

I just noticed that the author uses `"Article.date='{$date}'"` rather than `Article.date => $date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are escaped if you are using

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Article.date' => $this->request->data['Article']['date'],
 )
```

In the second example, you would need to be responsible to escape the `$date` variable first.

Where are you using the sanitize class now? The suggestions from the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#input-filtering) might apply to you case too.

Comment: I edited my post because I realized that the author uses `"Article.date='{$date}'"` rather than `Article.date => $date`.  Would the latter be escaped properly by cake?

Comment: it will not be escaped. To verify, you can make a simple test: send invalid data and check the `sql_dump` to see the query that is generated.

Comment: Thanks. So if I need to manipulate Posted data requiring a variable be used, I must escape that variable before using it in a find statement? Yes, I was using sanitize class (with 2.3.9). Regardless, I wanted to check on the sanitizing of find statements

Comment: You should try to use the `find` method with  array(
`'Article.date' => $this->request->data['Article']['date'],)` If that is not possible, either escape the data before using it, or maybe try to look into prepared statements too -- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements